# horizontal menu github style

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create horizontal menu that will be similar to GitHub menu:

[image: GitHub]

This what I have done so far:

[image: my menu]

here is my code on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/b3qL5/16/)

My problem is the hover effect that should be visible when I hover over non active elements.
On GitHub red line is done using:

```
.sunken-menu .sunken-menu-item.selected:after {
   background-color: #ba5d0f;
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#d26911, #ba5d0f);
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#d26911, #ba5d0f);
   background-image: linear-gradient(#d26911, #ba5d0f);
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
   box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

I've tried adding similar effect using border, but it isn't the same.
How can I fix this?

Secondly how can I display line below inactive element after hover? Right now I have line on top:

```
.menu .menu-item:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 0 #ccc;
}
```

Can I switch it to be on bottom using `box-shadow`?

Comment: Just flip de value :) ```box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 #ccc;``` and it's on bottom. To not display hover for active elements capture it with:  ```.menu-item.selected:hover { box-shadow: none; }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use border to indicate status here. Box-shadow is the way to go, since you can not get rid of the border-edges.

here is one version: http://jsfiddle.net/b3qL5/19/

```
.menu-item.selected {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    color: #333333;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 -3px 0 #ba5d0f;

}
.menu .menu-item:not(.selected):hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 #ccc;
}
```

If you want to have a more complex shadow on `.menu-item.selected` you can combine multiple shadows, but you will have to repeat the initial shadow or you override it. For example like this:

```
.menu .menu-item.selected:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 -3px 0 #ba5d0f, inset 0 0px 3px green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b3qL5/20/

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `not` selector in css to select all those elements that do not have the `selected` class which is the class you have used for designating active elements.

for putting the border below use the full notation of box-shadow like this

```
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0px 0 #ccc;
```

so your css would change from

```
 .menu .menu-item:hover {
     box-shadow: inset 0 2px 0 #ccc;
 }
```

to this

```
 .menu .menu-item:not(.selected)hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0px 0 #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/gG2p8/1/

Note that `:not(.selected)` selector is used to get only not selected menu-item.

Also when you use negative values on 3rd argument of `box-shadow` it draws the shadow from the bottom border.